# How to dynamically change the CSS style of a node-type?

Tags: theming

I want to modify dynamically the style of a page in base of your content type:
I tried with a preprocess function insert this code:

```
if(isset($variables['node'])){
  if($variables['node']->type=='article'){
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme','my_theme').'/css/style_node_article.css');
  }
  if($variables['node']->type=='page'){
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme','my_theme').'/css/style_node_page.css');
  }
}
```

This doesn't set the right CSS if I change page from article to page...
Thanks

Comment: looks right.  did you cleaer the cache.  You can also do if(isset($node)),  $node is available on any node page

Comment: Yes i have made that you tell me but when i visited a page the style is the same of the article and the condition is not right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have a ton of CSS you should add the CSS for all the nodes and use the node type class on the wrapper div of the node.

I can't remember the exact classes you can view them in the source. You could do something like this

```
.node {}
.node-page {}
.node-blog {}
```

Where the first class is on all nodes and the latter is dynamic for the node.

Comment: This is a way but i want to add css conditionally on a page based on a node type.. problably i dont understand what you tell me....sorry for english..

Comment: It's simple: do not use conditional css files (unless they are very, very large). Use the css selectors like div.node-blog instead to target specific content types.

Comment: I dont understand how to use the selector to modify all the style of a page and not one single css property..

Comment: Also, if you're using a sub-theme such as Zen, it gives you handy classes in the body tag with details of the content type.

Comment: Body classes are not limited to the Zen theme. Both D6 and D7 generate a number of body classes, regardless of the theme (but it's up to the theme to print them). This means that you can target every element in your page with a selector based on the body class. For instance: `body.node-type-blog a { color: #C00 }` would color all links red when viewing a blog node.

Comment: just wondering, why the advice against conitional loading in small themes? Does it make problems for css caching?

Comment: @mtro A single style sheet is simpler and a lot faster to develop. Less is more.